# ‘getaddrinfo’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c, sockets, casting, segmentation-fault

My program has the following warning because of which I think there is a core dump segmentation fault error showing up:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘getaddrinfo’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] 

rc = getaddrinfo(svrHost, svrPort, &hints, &res);
                           ^
In file included from client6_main.c:16:0:
/usr/include/netdb.h:662:12: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘short unsigned int’
extern int getaddrinfo (const char *__restrict __name,
```

The code segment is:

```
rc = getaddrinfo(svrHost, svrPort, &hints, &res);

if(rc != 0){
    printf("Host not found --> %s\n", gai_strerror(rc));
    if (rc == EAI_SYSTEM)
        perror("getaddrinfo() failed");
}
```

Please guide

Comment: Well, what is the type of 'svrPort'?

Comment: The second argument of `getaddrinfo` must be of type `const char*`. Read the fine manual.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the service name or the port number as a decimal string as second parameter of the `getaddrinfo` call.

For that, just change the type of the variable `svrPort` from `unsigned short` to  `char*` or `char const*`, and make it point to a valid string.

For example, `"http"` or `"80"` instead of `80`.

Comment: You can very well use 80, but as a string `"80"`.

Comment: You are right, indeed, I overlooked that. Edited your comment in.

Comment: Also "Either node or service, but not both, may be NULL."

Answer (score 1):

The first two function arguments are expected to be pointers to strings.

```
int getaddrinfo(const char *node, 
                const char *service,
                const struct addrinfo *hints,
                struct addrinfo **res);
```

I assume from the warning you got that `svrPort` is of type `int`.
The compiler will treat this in as a pointer. If `svrPort` is initialized to `1234` then the function will lookup a string starting at address 1234 which may or may not be a valid address.

You should probably pass `NULL` or `0` to tell `getaddrinfo` to ignore this argument.